# Plot data point according to their class labels in Python

Tags: python, r, plot

I am trying to plot data points whose color corresponds to their class labels. I am more familiar with R in terms of data visualization. In R, I would do the following:

```
x = matrix(runif(100), 2, 20)
y = matrix(runif(100), 2, 20)
labels = c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 20))
plot(rbind(x, y), col = labels)
```

Then I will be able to have a scatter plot of data points from two classes and their point colors are the labels. I am not sure how to do this in python. So far what I did was

```
import numpy
plot(numpy.vstack((x,y)), c = labels)
```

But apparently python does not like integer values for colors.... Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `numpy` and `matplotlib` libraries. That should get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You have three vectors of data: `x`, `y`, and `c`, where `c` is an integer array with class labels.

The simplest thing you can do is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some random data grouped into three groups
x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.random.random(100)
c = np.random.choice(range(3), 100)

# plot the data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# plot x,y data with c as the color vector, set the line width of the markers to 0
ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, lw=0)
```

This gives you:

[image]

If you want more control over your colors, you may even create your own color table, for example:

```
mycolors = np.array([ 'g', 'm', 'c' ])
ax.scatter(x, y, c=mycolors[c], lw=0)
```

And now the colors are 0=green, 1=magenta, 2=cyan:

[image]

Of course, you may also specify color triplets (RGB) or quadruplets (RGBA) instead of the color names. This gives you a more granular control.

You may also use the built-in colormaps or create your own. I just find the above solution the most transparent with discrete data with only few possible values.